# connect 2 different lan's for internet access and DMZ

Tags: networking, router, vpn, lan, dmz

i got 2 routers one has ip address like 192.168.1.1 and is connected to my ISP's fast internet access

My ISP does not provide me with static ip services so i bought static ip vpn service from vpnstaticip.com (czech ip while im located in greece myself) which uses a second router with lan ip 192.168.100.1 and which is connected through the first router (from router 2's wan port to router 1's lan port)

My whole lan is behind router 2 (192.168.100.*) so all my network has ip's like 192.168.100.x and i have internet and i can access all LAN's resources

### THE PROBLEM:

Because i effectively now connect to the internet via vpn and router 2 for all my lan (which limits my download speed up to 10mpbps the max because i connect through czech) while my ISP supports up to 30mbps

Also i got x2 server's which are accessible via this static ip directly through dmz and host web and mail server's

What i want for my lan is fast internet access, and not to access the internet through vpn but i also want my server's publicly accessible.

One solution would be to connect all my lan to router 1's network (192.168.1.*) which is connected directly to my ISP and get 30mbps down speed but then router 2 (192.168.100.*) along with my static ip will be unable to access the server's as they will be in different subnet's and router 2 will not allow me to port forward or dmz to an ip in different subnet (like 192.168.1.55)

I also cannot connect just the servers to router 2 and have the rest of my lan on router 1 as i use those server's as file server's also and i guess again they will not be accessible via samba etc etc.

QUESTION:

is there a way that i can have all my lan behind router 1 and have my server's accessible both from inside my lan and outside (through the static ip vpn service) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, change the IP blocks and gateways and turn off DHCP on your 2nd router.
Or, Add a second IP to your servers ethernet interface.

First case .. First Router 192.168.1.x with 192.168.1.1 as lan gateway, dhcp left on.  Your servers get set to *static* ip, and set a gateway for the **2nd** router's LAN port.

The 2nd router you have to change the IP block to 192.168.1.x common choice is to make the 2nd router's Lan address (and by definition a gateway address) to be 192.168.1.254.

Alternate and probably easier - statically set your servers with their 192.168.100.x IP addresses, with a gateway of your 192.168.100.1 router. You **must** turn off DHCP on the 2nd router. Add a second IP address to your servers in the 192.168.1.x IP range.  The rest of your devices should be set for DHCP and get their ip address from your ISP router.

In the alternate version, both routers would connect to the same switch (again thats why you **must** turn off DHCP on the second router) and all of your machines would connect to the switch.  By nature of the default route setting, and by statically setting your Servers' ip addresses, they will only go 192.168.100.1 BUT by having a second address on the 192.168.1.x network, your other machines would be able to access them.

[image: Additional IP address Dialog - Windows]

Comment: Hi thanks for your email, my x2 servers have x2 lan interfaces but both are used one for switch and second for heartbeat on both they are in a cluster and i dont have a 3d lan port to do it this way :/ As for the first scenario you say // and set a gateway for the 2nd router's LAN port.
The 2nd router you have to change the IP block to 192.168.1.x //  set a gateway for 2nd router's lan port you mean set a static route on first router ? So both routers will be in the 192.168.1.* range? im confused can you elaborate? cheers

Comment: You're not putting 3 network cards with 3 different IP addresses.  Its *one* card, plugged into 1 switch port, but with multiple IP address.  Look at the picture, that would be 1 network card, you hit advanced, and then can add multiple IP addresses.

Comment: I understand now great but i have a problem i got synology servers (linux) and they dont support dual ip for single lan interface :/ any other solution ? maybe if i put a 3d router in between as a gateway to connect the 2 subnets? but how I go about to do that ? thanks

Comment: I read somewgere that i can put a 3d router in between connect the router 1's lan port to router 3 wan port and router 2 lan with router 3 lan and disable nat and dhcp on 3d router then add static routes to the other 2 routers ? but I'm not sure? cheers

Comment: Which model Synology? If it supports SSH & get to the box, you should be able to set up multiple ifcfg-ethX:X files to alias IP's. I've been in there, when setting up one and temporarly set IP's using ifup commands.  This page,  http://mysynology.nl/alias-aanmaken-via-winscp/ , you'll probably have to translate they have people using WinSCP to download config files (http, etc), edit them, and then put them back up on the server.  Its a linux distro at its core, networking scripts go to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ ** note turn off auto update and backup your manual config files